# Any circle in sphere is intersection of the sphere and a unique plane.

Tags: trigonometry, stereographic-projections

I would like to prove the existence and uniqueness of such a plane $P$, the truth is I can't think of a relatively simple way to prove it.

Let $\Lambda$ be a circle lying in $S$. Then there is a unique plane $P$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $P\cap S=\Lambda$. Recall from analytic geometry that 
$$P=\left\{(x_1,x_2,x_3):\beta_1 x_1+\beta_2 x_2+\beta_3 x_3-l=0\right\}$$
where $(\beta_1,\beta_2,\beta_3)$ is a vector orthogonal to $P$ and $l$ is some real number.
Use this information to show that if $\Lambda$ contains the point $N$ then its projection on $\mathbb{C}$ is a straight line. Otherwise, $\Lambda$ projects onto a circle in $\mathbb{C}$.

My solution:

By the hint, exists a unique plane  $P=\left\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in\mathbb{R}^3:\beta_1x_1+\beta_2x_2+\beta_3x_2-l=0\right\}$ such that $P\cap S=\Lambda$.\
Let $(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in \Lambda$ then $\varphi((x_1,x_2,x_3))=x+iy\in \mathbb{C}$ where $\displaystyle x=\frac{2x}{1-x_3},\ y=\frac{2y}{1-x_3}$ with $\varphi$ stereographic projection.

Moreover, for $z=x+iy$ it representation  $\left(x_1,x_2,x_3\right)$ in $S$ is
$\displaystyle(x_1,x_2,x_3)=\left(\frac{2x}{|z|^2+1},\frac{2y}{|z|^2+1},\frac{|z|^2-1}{|z|^2+1}\right)$. If this point belongs in $P$,

$$\beta_1\left(\frac{2x}{x_1^2+x_2^2+1}\right)+\beta_2\left(\frac{2y}{x_1^2+x_2^2+1}\right)+\beta_3\left(\frac{x_1^2+x_2^2-1}{x_1^2+x_2^2+1}\right)-l=0$$
equivalent to
\begin{align}\label{ecuacion}(\beta_3-l)x^2+2\beta_1x+(\beta_3-l)y^2+2\beta_2y-\beta_3-l=0
\end{align}
If $N=(0,0,1)\in \Lambda$ then $\beta_1\cdot 0+\beta_2 0+1\cdot \beta_3-l=0$, e.g. $\beta_3-l=0$, so, the equation  has the form
$$Ax+By+C=0$$
where $A=2\beta_1,\ B=2\beta_2,\ C=\beta_3-l$, general line equation.

If $N=(0,0,1)\not\in \Lambda$ then $\beta_3-l\neq 0$, so, the equation  has the form
$$Ax^2+By^2+Cx+Dy+E=0$$
 where $A=B=\beta_3-l\neq 0,\ C=2\beta_1,\ D=2\beta_2,\ E=-\beta_3-l$, general circumference equation

Comment: Every circle defines a unique plane.  That plane of course intersects the circle and hence the sphere.  Why isn't that enough of a proof?

Comment: This is not what you have to show. What you have to show is the stuff after "show" in the problem statement

Comment: yes but I will like provethis

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I think OP is looking for a rigorous analytic proof. What exactly is your question OP? Are you looking for a simple proof?

Comment: I will like proves that:
Let $\Lambda$ circle in $S$, then exists a unique plane $P$ such that $P\cap S=\Lambda.$

Comment: We may take "more-then-one-point intersection of a sphere and a plane" as *definition* of a circle in 3d space

Comment: @eraldcoil How do you define a circle in $\Bbb{R}^3$?

Comment: that is my problem... I dont know the definition

Comment: For the old Greek, a circle was the set of point in **the** plane that have a common distance to a point in **the** plane. For 3d, replace **the** plane with **a** plane and the definition of *sphere* as set of all points at a common distance from a point. That gives us a nice *definition:* Intersection of a sphere with a plane through the centre of the sphere. Then use Pythagoras to show a nice *theorem* that the intersection of any sphere and plane is either a circle or a point or empty ...

Comment: Will the following argument work? Let $(x_1,x_2,x_3),\ ({x'}_1,{x'}_2,{x'}_3)\in \Lambda$ two diametrically opposite points
, along with another two diametrically opposite points
 $({x''}_1,{x''}_2,{x''}_3),\ ({x'''}_1,{x'''}_2,{x'''}_2)$ then  $(\beta_1,\beta_2,\beta_3):=

(x_1-x_2,{x'}_2-x_2,{x'}_3-x_3)\times ({x''}_1-{x'''}_1,{x''}_2-{x'''}_2,{x''}_3-{x'''}_3)$ is orthogonal to 

$\Lambda$, so $\left\{(x_1,x_2,x_3):\beta_1 x_1+\beta_2x_2+\beta_3-l=0\right\}$ is such that $P\cap S=\Lambda$

Comment: What are you even trying to prove in this argument (previous comment)? By claiming that $\vec \beta$ is orthogonal to all of $\Lambda$, you are simply assuming that $\Lambda$ is planar. But if you already know that, then there is no need to figure out an expression for $\vec \beta$. $\Lambda$ lies in some plane $P$ by definition. Since $\Lambda\subset P$ and $\Lambda\subset S$, we have $\Lambda \subset P\cap S$. Since $P\cap S$ is not empty or a single point, it must be a circle (planes and spheres intersect in circles, single points, or not at all), and therefore it must be $\Lambda$.